python cv2 image freeze script wayland
Hi to all Im using vscode on venv folder to run script to generate image. I was able to get clear image with PIL but need to refresh the image continously and PIL generate a lot of pictures. So I triedd to use cv2 with cv2.imshow(), but sudenly the program stop working and this erros is shown:
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland"

In the venv I got installed opnecv.python, also install Qt5 and PIL. I tried settings in the bashrc this lines:
#QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
#QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
#QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen

search in the /etc/gdm3/custom.config and uncomment the wayland line: WaylandEnable=false
But the problem persist. The script generate only one time the image and then stop working, vscode throws error. Also I tried to unistall opencv-python and install opncv-python-headless but throws another error.
Is a cleaner way to refresh an image with cv2 or PIL? i got an numpy array RGB like this:
    RGB_values=np.array(RGB_values, dtype=np.uint64).reshape(xdim,ydim)  
    R = (RGB_values&0xF800)>>8
    G = (RGB_values&0x07E0)>>3
    B = (RGB_values&0x001F)<<3
    RGB888 = np.dstack((R, G, B)).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imshow('image',RGB888) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)

also if I remove the cv2.waitKey(-1) the image is not generated. How to solve this problem?
Regards
Gaston
install - unistall opencv-python, uncomment wayland on custom.conf. Set environment variables on bashrc. Im using vscode on folder with venv

If they are 16-bit values, why use np.uint64?  And what do you mean by "PIL generate a lot of pictures"?  That's what you wanted, isn't it?

[mre] please...

you are running this on a headless system like a server or raspberry pi, aren't you?

Hi to all, Im running this on ubuntu OS 64. Im trying to refresh an image and using PIL is not possible that is why I stearted to use cv2. But with cv2 got this warning about Qt and wayland and the program just stop....the image is generated just once

I'll ask again: is that a headless system or not?
